# How can I unlock my Pixel phone?

Tags: google-account, google-pixel, pattern-lock, google-pixel-4a

Last night I added a pattern lock on my Pixel 4a before sleeping. After waking up today, I cannot remember the exact pattern. I can only remember that it was a zigzag pattern. After failing several times trying to figure out the pattern, I got locked out and cannot even use my fingerprint anymore. Most of the resources on the internet seems to suggest that I will need to erase my phone to unlock it. That will be very disheartening since I did not backup any of my photos. I am wondering whether any of the following is possible-

- Use my google account on a different device to unlock my phone.
- Use my google account to remotely backup my photos in google photos
- Use a third party software to extract photos from my device without unlocking it

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you make updates? https://twitter.com/xdavidhu